# chatbot using twisted and wokkel

Tags: python, twisted, xmpp, chatbot

I am writing a chatbot using Twisted and wokkel and everything seems to be working except that bot periodically logs off. To temporarily fix that I set presence to available on every connection initialized. Does anyone know how to prevent going offline? (I assume if i keep sending available presence every minute or so bot wont go offline but that just seems too wasteful.) Suggestions anyone? Here is the presence code:

```
class BotPresenceClientProtocol(PresenceClientProtocol):

    def connectionInitialized(self):
        PresenceClientProtocol.connectionInitialized(self)
        self.available(statuses={None: 'Here'})

    def subscribeReceived(self, entity):
        self.subscribed(entity)
        self.available(statuses={None: 'Here'})

    def unsubscribeReceived(self, entity):
        self.unsubscribed(entity)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sometimes IRC networks want you to respond to pings. That might be a possible cause of disconnect.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using XMPP, as I assume is the case given your mention of `wokkel`, then, per [RFC 3921](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920), the applicable standard, you do need periodic exchanges of presence information (indeed, that's a substantial overhead of XMPP, and solutions to it are being researched, but that's the state of the art as of now).  Essentially, given the high likelihood that total silence from a client may be due to that client just going away, periodic "reassurance" of the kind "I'm still here" appears to be a must (I'm not sure what direction those research efforts are taking to ameliorate this situation -- maybe the client could commit to "being there for at least the next 15 minutes", but given that most clients are about a fickle human user who can't be stopped from changing their mind at any time and going away, I'm not sure that would be solid enough to be useful).

Comment: hmm interesting. i was hoping there would be some kind of a ping mechanism e.g. server tries to ask client for their state just before it assumes client is offline (like tom mentioned in a comment above for irc networks). oh well. thank you.

Comment: @dmitry, I believe you can implement that conformantly as an XMPP extension, but it's not specified as part of the standard and I believe (though I might be wrong!) that wokkel has no such extension (if it did you could surely find it spelled out in the wokkel docs).

Comment: Many XMPP clients and servers will periodically send a single space if they haven't sent or received traffic recently.  This is enough to wake up the TCP stream, and eventually cause timeouts that will mark that client as unavailable.